# ansible install mysql 5.6 on ubuntu 14

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-14.04, ansible

I am using ansible and would like to install mysql 5.6. I am also using vagrant and virtualbox.

Currently this will install mysql 5.5 in my tasks main.yml file

```
- name: mysql | Install MySQL Packages
  sudo: yes
  apt: pkg={{ item }} state=latest
```

Any ideas on how to install 5.6

```
- name: mysql | Install MySQL Packages
  sudo: yes
  apt: pkg="mysql-server-5.6" state=latest
```

Answer (score 3):

I was able to change to this below to get it to finally work:

```
- name: mysql | Install MySQL Packages
  sudo: yes
  apt: pkg={{ item }} state=latest
  with_items:
    - mysql-server-5.6
    - mysql-client-5.6
    - python-mysqldb
```